# N/A as N/A not as not a number in pandas and python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nan, na

I´m working in excel using pandas and python. I have something like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv("abx.csv")
df1 = df.loc[df["Application Name"].str.contains(r"(\N\/\A)")]
df1.set_index("User ID", inplace = True)
df1.to_csv("abx1.csv")
```

In this case, I´m trying to filter the column "Application Name" that contains the string N/A. But when i run this code i receive this error

```
raise ValueError('cannot index with vector containing '
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

I think the problem is the compiler is taking N/A as the not a number value, not as the N/A string.

Any idea. I will appreciate the help. Thanks and sorry for bad english

Comment: try this `df1 = df[df["Application Name"].str.contains(r"(\N\/\A)")]`

Comment: `df['Application Name'].fillna('NA', inplace=True)` will replace any missing values with the string `NA`.

Comment: BTW, if you want to match a string `N/A`, the regex will look the same, `r"N/A"`.

Comment: @MYGz aside from the duff regex pattern, even if it was valid you can't use a boolean array to index a df using `loc`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, I know the regex will be the same, i was trying to use \ just in case.

Comment: @EdChum I receive the same error message.

Comment: did you try `df1 = df[df["Application Name"].str.contains(r"N/A")]`? also do you have `NaN` values in that column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`keep_default_na=False` will indicate to `read_csv` to not interpret NA strings at load time. Thus any NA string from the csv file will be kept as such and your code will work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("abx.csv", keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: very clean and precise!